# Why position of div is affected by margin-top of its child?

Tags: html, css

Here is my markup

CSS

```
body{
    background-color:#353535;    
}
#parent{
    background-color:#eee;
}
#child{
    background-color:#1b1b1b;
    margin:60px auto 10px;
    width:100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">child</div>
</div>
```

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/W74TZ/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Margin collapsing rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins). If the margin-top reaches the top of the `<body>` without anything conflicting ( like a padding-top:1px on #parent ) then the parent will "inherit" that.

You can avoid this by setting a `padding-top:60px` on `#parent` instead.

Answer (score 4):

It's part of the CSS spec. You can read up more on this by Googling "margin collapsing", e.g. http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing