# <body> doesn't reach at the top of the page

Tags: html, css

Baffled, this is the `html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Welcome</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/Styles/CompiledLESS.less" />
    <script src="/Scripts/JS/less-1.5.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainContentDiv">
            <div>
                <h2>Please Log In</h2>
                <p>You must <a href="/Account">Log in</a> to use.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`CSS` is this:

```
body {
    background-color: #D5E6ED;
    background-image: url("~/Images/Background.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #444444;
    font-family: Verdana,Tahoma,Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 71%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#mainContentDiv
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 997px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

I can't see anything wrong but the result is the `<body>` tag is not flush with the top of the browser window when I inspect it with firebug.

There is no other `CSS`, that's the entirety of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2faG/)

```
h2{
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Because h2 is a block level element, so has its default margin and padding.

Comment: But surely the body would still be at the top of the page? The h2 should just create a margin inside the body, no?

Comment: That's because some elements come with default styles and you need to override them if you want them to act differently.

Comment: @BinitaTamang In fact, this happens because of [margin collapsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493402/why-position-of-div-is-affected-by-margin-top-of-its-child). `margin-top` of the first element, affects the parent position.

Comment: Thanks Hashem for the information. I guess, in your design, design would start right from top. Since your beginning element is h2, hence the margin.

Comment: What is there to do in the case when i _want_ some margin on `h2`?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
*{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: please add more information, explaining your answer and what the questioner was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify `position:absolute;` and `top:0;` for your #mainContentDiv

Answer (score 0):

Binita is right; though we should set below properties default to 0 at the top of CSS:

```
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, form, input, button, textarea, p, th, td, a
{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-left-width: 0px;
}
```